# Add a child dynamically with an animation

Tags: c#, silverlight

We could always add a child (or insert) to a root node dynamically. But how would be go about adding this child with an animation effect. For example adding a rectangle below an existing rectangle in a grid, I want it get added with a slide down effect.

Thanks guys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the child to the root node in a collapsed state.  Then, animate the transition from collapsed to expanded.  It will seem (visually) that the addition of the child was itself animated.

Comment: Thats awesome. Please could you guide me how to add animation for collapsed to expanded (in a moving slide down manner)?  In a storyboard should I use visible property of the rectangle? If yes - then what kind would it be - double - probably no, point -probably no, color - probably no? I have done such things in adobe flex but am quite new to silverlight. A code snippet (c#, since doing it all dynamically) would really help. Many thanks again for your help...

Comment: Or maybe Instead of visibility I should concentrate on Height and then I could change it from 0 to y using DubleAnimation property? But then the question will be how would I know the value of "y" required height (which could vary depending on other child components of this element) at run time? Thanks again...

Comment: You are correct, I meant to say you add it as collapsed, then set its height to 0, set it to expanded, and then animate height from 0 to target height.  As for how to compute the target height, I believe there is a property for Height;  you want to be animating a property named 'ActualHeight' from 0 to Height.  I can't confirm this at the moment, but I can look into it more at a later time.